# $http.get request gets string instead of json on success (Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, angularjs, http

The controller returns data, however I can't iterate over it in the HTML file. However using the expression {{phones}} directly displays the data returned. I believe the data is being returned as a string instead of json. I am expecting the names and snippets corresponding to all the data returned in the loop.

```
<body ng-app="phonecatApp" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl" >
    Search: <input ng-model="query">
    Sort By:
    <select ng-model="orderByFilter">
        <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
        <option value="age">Numerical</option>
    </select>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | orderBy:orderByFilter">
            <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
            <span>{{phone.snippet}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script src="~/Scripts/AngularScript.js"></script>

</body>
```

Angular js script

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('Home/GetJson').success(function (data){        
        $scope.phones = data;
    });
});
```

Controller Action method

```
public JsonResult GetJson()
        {
            string variablename = "[{'name': 'Nexus S','snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.', 'age': 1}]";
            return Json (variablename, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a data in JSON format, you don't need to use method `Json`, because it serializes the object once again under the covers. You can use method `Content` instead:

```
public ActionResult GetJson()
{
    string variablename = "[{'name': 'Nexus S','snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.', 'age': 1}]";
    return Content(variablename);
}
```

Alternatively instead of providing hardcoded data you can create an object, and allow method `Json` to serialize the object:

```
public ActionResult GetJson()
{
    var resultObject = new object [] {
        new {
            name="Nexus S",
            snippet= "Fast just got faster with Nexus S.", 
            age= 1
        }
    };
    return Json (resultObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix this issue on the client side. Just parse response before setting it to `phones`

```
$scope.phones = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe that you are passing the content as String because it is already serialized into JSON rather than an Object.

You can return that content this way:

```
public ActionResult GetJson()
{
    string variablename = "[{'name': 'Nexus S','snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.', 'age': 1}]";
    return Content (variablename, "application/json");                
}
```

However, the best option would be to pass an object and let `Json()` serialize it as @dotnetom indicated in this answer.